# how to extract matrix from big matrix in torch/lua

Tags: lua, torch

In torch7 / lua

There is a matrix:

```
[  1,  2,  3,  4;
   5,  6,  7,  8;
   9, 10, 11, 12;
  13, 14, 15, 16  ]
```

how to extract this:

```
[  6,  7;
  10, 11  ]
```

and how to overwrite it by matrix operation

```
[  1,  2,  3,  4;
   5, 78, 66,  8;
   9, 45, 21, 12;
  13, 14, 15, 16  ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix

matrix:sub(2,3,2,3)

z = torch.Tensor({{78,66},{45,21}})

matrix:sub(2,3,2,3):copy(z)
```