# How to update a segment in the matrix in Torch/Lua?

Tags: lua, torch

I'm trying to update a segment in the matrix in Torch, but I have not got a simple function to do it.

For example: `$ x = torch.Tensor(5, 6):zero() -- create a matrix`

and I tried to update a segment in the matrix like:

`$ x[{ 2,{2,4} }]= {1, 2, 3}` and

`$ x[{ 2,{2,4} }]:fill({1,2,3})`

Neither of them works.

Should I just do it with a loop or does there exist a simple function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994241/how-to-extract-matrix-from-big-matrix-in-torch-lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a tensor instead of trying to directly assign a table:

```
x[{2, {2,4}}] = torch.Tensor({1, 2, 3})
```